# MS SQL Server - check if you have more money then you shall pay

Tags: c#, sql-server

Hej, im trying to check if i got enough money for a purchase, how do i check that in c# and MS SQL Server?

I have tried

```
" SELECT Money FROM [User] WHERE Isactive ='1' IF (SELECT Money FROM [User] >= '"+ customPayTextBox.Text+"') UPDATE [User] SET Money WHERE Isactive ='1' = Money - 100"
```

I have also tried without the `SELECT Money FROM [User]` under the if statement.

Am I doing it all wrong?

How do it implament it in c#? Can I get a true or false in return when I run this command on a button click? Or would the command not run if I don't have enough money for a purchase?

Comment: Are you sure you use MySQL? The syntax suggests ms sql server. Also, pls include the c# code as well.

Comment: Can you should provide more information about the context of your problem?

Comment: There is no need for select, you can do this in a single update

Comment: Please note that your update query ` UPDATE [User]
    SET Money = Money - 100` updates all rows within the user table  because there is no WHERE to filter

Comment: `IF (SELECT Money FROM [User] >= '"+ customPayTextBox.Text+"')` Did you hear something about injection SQL ?

Comment: Please improve the formatting of the code - as it's written right now, it's much more difficult to read.

Comment: I have no clue why it were listed like that before, but i have fixed it. my problem is that, when i substract money with 100, i want to check if my account got 100$ if not, i will show a message that says you dont have enough money.. right now my account are just going in minus

Comment: @MortenSyhlerJensen That goes back to my point above about formatting your code properly - it's *much* easier to read (and, therefore, much easier to spot potential problems) if you format it reasonably.

Comment: Isnt that formatted right?

Comment: Does not look like a MySQL to me.  Please tag properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `SELECT` statement is neither needed nor stored.
This can all be done by using a `WHERE` clause within the `UPDATE` statement.

I have written this based on SQL Server syntax and have parameterized the query to avoid SQL Injection. With neither your C# code nor db schema I went with a generic Sql Connection & Command typing; so you most likely will have to adjust this for your circumstances.

Another thing you are going to need is to identify which row is to be updated, I have generic'd this as well with the `UserID` paramaeter.

```
int rowsAffected;
string connString = "";
int Money = (int)customPayTextBox.Text;

using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString)) {
    conn.Open();
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand()) {
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE [User] SET Money = Money - 100 WHERE (IsActive = '1') AND (UserID = @UserID) AND (Money >= @Money);";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Money", Money);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", UserID);

        rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    conn.Close();
}

if (rowsAffected == 0) { /* user not found OR not enough funds */ }
else { /* at least 1 row was updated */ }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a few problems here. First,

```
SELECT Money FROM [User] >= '"+ customPayTextBox.Text+"'
```

the `SELECT Money FROM [User]` may return more than one row.

Secondly,

```
'"+ customPayTextBox.Text+"'
```

You shouldn't build a query with unverified user input like that; for one thing, you don't know if `customPayTextBox.Text` actually has a valid integer in it. For another thing, it's a risk for a [SQL Injection Attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Third,

```
UPDATE [User]
SET Money = Money - 100
```

will just subtract 100 from *every row* in the database (at least in SQL Server, I haven't tested on MySQL). I'm not sure if that's what you're trying to do here.

Finally, the first query:

```
SELECT Money
FROM [User]
WHERE Isactive ='1'
```

won't actually do anything useful here - you neither store nor use the result.

Also, I strongly recommend formatting your code well; it makes it a lot easier to read and understand (and, therefore, a lot easier to debug, maintain, and proofread for potential issues).

**Edit:** Here's an example query for the following table structure:

```
--------------------
| UserID | [Money] |
--------------------
| 1      | 0       |
| 2      | 100     |
| 3      | 200     |
--------------------
```

The following code (using SQL Server syntax):

```
IF ((select [Money] FROM MyTestTable WHERE ID = 1) >= 100)
    PRINT 'Yes' -- Substitute whatever action you want here
ELSE -- Include this if you want to take some action if they don't have enough money
    PRINT 'No' -- Again, substitute whatever action you want here
```

will print `Yes` if user 1 has at least $100 and `No` if they have less than $100.

You can also do something like this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN ((select top 1 [Money] FROM MyTestTable WHERE ID = 1) >= 100) then 1 else 0 END
```

to just return true/false (it'll be `true`/`false` in MySQL I think).

Comment: okay, that my bad, what i added "WHERE Isactive = '1'" to the code.
but my problem here is to check if i got enough money on that active account, how do it check that.

Comment: @MortenSyhlerJensen That's only a partial fix for the problem because it's still at least logically possible for the query to return multiple rows.

Comment: Thats right, but in my application, there is only one online at time right now, so for this it wont be a problem

Comment: @MortenSyhlerJensen The key phrase is "only one online at one time **right now**". What happens when you start having several users online at once?

Comment: That wont happen for this application, because it just to me for start learing the basic about mysql in c#

Comment: @MortenSyhlerJensen Fair enough. In any case, I edited to include an example (using SQL Server syntax, but it should be easy enough to modify it for MySQL syntax) of selecting whether or not the user has enough money.

Comment: Thanks, but how do check if it were a yes or no in c#? wanna show an error if it's print 'No'

Comment: @MortenSyhlerJensen Most database systems have some kind of Boolean type built in - for example, it's `BIT` in Sql Server and `BOOLEAN` in MySQL. Generally, you can just select a column of that type and cast it to bool in C#. It's similar to selecting and casting any other column, there's nothing particularly "special" about that type.

Comment: Sorry, i coulnt make it work, i still cant get my head around it, i used Mad Myche method.